# is it possible to browse files from my iphone application placed at any location in the device?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

I wanted to browse iPhone device for files like text,pdf,images etc. like in android we can browse in memory card to upload or attach files. But for iPhone, i searched a lot but i didn't find any solution to do this.

Comment: Is this a user-level question or a programming question? Is this for a jailbroken device or regular?

Comment: @rmaddy it is programming level question. i am building iphone application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For regular device, the answer is NO.

Every app in iOS runs on its [sandbox environment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html). Your app can't see any data placed outside of the sandbox.

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

For jailbroken device, it will break the snadbox environment. So it may be possible to access any files in your device.

Comment: sry i forgot to mention, that it is programming level question, but from ur answer it seems that its not possible at that level also. But is there any alternative to do this..?? thnx in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
       Never do that becose  your app will be rejected,
       if you do like that and upload your app on App Store..... 
       Never use jailbreak in your app friend..
```

Comment: thanx , i was not knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

To pick image use UIImagePicker

```
UIImagePickerController*    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    imagePicker.sourceType      =   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes      =   [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
    imagePicker.delegate        =   self;
    imagePicker.editing         =   YES;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing   =   YES;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To pick files and pdf, use FileManager

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:@"/MYFOLDER"];
NSArray *pdfList = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.pdf'"]];
NSLog(@"%@", pdfList);
```

Comment: The OP asks for a method to pick files outside his apps' sandbox. Also `directoryContentsAtPath` is deprecated since iOS 2.0:"Returns the directories and files (including symbolic links) contained in a given directory. (Deprecated in iOS 2.0. Use contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: instead.)"

Comment: @Shob-Z thanx for ur help but i want to create interface like we browse files in windows..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but it uses private API's. Your app will be rejected if you use this and submit to the app store. 
Check this opensource lib [FileSystem](https://github.com/macmade/FileSystem)